# Insert data attribute into url

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I insert the `data-url` attribute from a div into a load function dynamically by click?

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
  $("#data").load("https://website.com/data/some-keywords-needed .content", function() {

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link" data-url="some keywords needed"></div>
```

And its also important that the keywords are connected in the `url` by a `"-"`.

**The solution**

```
$(".link").click(function() {
  var myUrl = "https://website.com/data/" + $(this).attr('data-url').replace(/\W/g, '-')
  $("#data").load(myUrl + " .content", function() {
  console.log(myUrl);
  });
});
```

Thx to all for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery's `attr` function to get the attribute's value and then replace all whitespace using the `replace` function:

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
  var myUrl = "https://website.com/data/" + $(this).attr('data-url').replace(/\W/g, '-')
  console.log(myUrl)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link" data-url="some keywords needed">Link</div>
```

Comment: Same here ... it looks like variables dont work with "load"? ;( Or I do something wrong ... how would the part ".load" looks like at your way?

Comment: Variables do work with `load`. But you have to make sure that you `load` a valid existing html file you are allowed to download (beware [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)). Use something like `$("#data").load(myUrl, function(response, status, xhr ) { console.log(status) });` to find out if the download was successful.

Comment: OK, good to know. The load function works fine, if I insert an static url. So I think I insert the variable at the wrong way? Thats my try:

"$( "#data" ).load(myUrl + ".content", function() { ...

Comment: You can check if `myUrl="your static url"` works for you. If yes, make sure that your concatenation is correct.

Comment: I have updated my question / version on top for better handling and showing the actual problem.

Comment: Maybe you want to change `.load(myUrl + ".content", ...` to `.load(myUrl + " .content", ...` (added a space before the `.content`)?

Answer (score 3):

in var dataUrl is text from data-url attribute and convert space  () into `-`

```
    $( ".link" ).click(function() {
        var url = "https://website.com/data/" + $(this).data('url').replace(" ", "-");
        // your code
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like variables dont work with "load"? ;( Or I do something wrong ... how would the part "your code" look like at your way?

Comment: `$("#data").load(url + " .content", function() {
   alert('data is loaded')
  });`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.target`. `event` is passed to the handler function. Use `event.target` to get handle to the element that was clicked.

```
$( ".link" ).click(function(event) {
        const dataUrl = event.target.getAttribute("data-url");

        $( "#data" ).load( `https://website.com/data/${dataUrl}.content`, function() {
   });
});
```

Comment: Hm, have you a fiddle? I think this part "`https://website.com/data/${dataUrl}.content`" will not work for me ...

Comment: Thx! Strange, I get "null" at my variable at the console, even though I use exact the same code like you.

Comment: Just to make sure ... its s back tick `` in `.load` function

Comment: Yes, so far all is correctly written - I really dont understand whats my fail, but I will take a look for it the next days. The other solution now works for me, but big thx for your help!